# How do I resolve this issue of sqlite?

Tags: database, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I'm new to this. I have tried running "run selected Query" for the following command:

```
-- SQLite
INSERT INTO Users (Id, UserName)
VALUES (1, "Bob");

INSERT INTO Users (Id, UserName)
VALUES (2, "Tom");

INSERT INTO Users (Id, UserName)
VALUES (3, "Jane");
```

I have received the following error:

```
[10:55:09 AM][vscode-sqlite][ERROR] UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.Id
[10:55:52 AM][vscode-sqlite][ERROR] UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.Id
```

I don't know how to continue. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's quite obvious that there already are rows with those `Id`s in your database, and `Id` is an unique key.

There are a couple things you can do, and which is sensible depends on what you're really trying to do (and your database schema). I've tried to order these from more sensible to less sensible.

1. Use another `Id` for new rows. If the `Id` column is set autoincrement, you don't need to pass it at all. `INSERT INTO USERS (UserName) VALUES ("Ali");` If it's not, `INSERT INTO USERS (Id, UserName) VALUES (4, "Ali");` and so on.
2. Delete the old rows so you can use the same Ids.
3. Make the `Id` column non-unique.